# Modifying certain fields in array of objects

Tags: angularjs

I get some objects from a server that look like this:

```
{
   "id": 1",
   "name": "Jim"
}
```

I toss them in `$scope.myThings`, modify them in my app, adding some fields, they end up looking like this:

```
{    
   "id": 1",
   "name": "Jim",
   "favoriteFood": "Noodles"
}
```

Perhaps I get an update from the server, changing Jims name. I'd like to take the array of objects I get back from the server and apply their changes to the list that's in $scope without having to replace the list entirely (ie: `$scope.myThings = newData)` or having to iterate through comparing IDs.

Is there a method to do this?

Comment: Are you using underscore? If you are, there is a pretty handy method called `_.extend` used like so: `_.extend(originalObject, propsToExtendOriginalObjectWith)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [angular.merge](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge).

It's working with object and arrays.

**usage**

`angular.merge(dst, src);`

`dst`   **Object** Destination object.

`src`   **Object**  Source object(s).

For example:

`var a = [{x:4}]; var b=[{x:2,y:3}]; angular.merge(a,b);`

**result:**
`a=[{x: 2,y: 3}]`

`var a = [{x:4}]; var b=[{x:2,y:3}]; angular.merge(b,a);`

**result:**
`b=[{x: 4,y: 3}]`